# bash completion in msysgit by single or double tab

Tags: bash, git, msysgit

Single tab used to make bash complete current line, and double tab shown all possible variants.

For example, if I have files (or git branches, or whatever is suitable in current context) "abc", "abd" and "bbb", then if I type "git add a" console will look like that:

```
// start
id@IDANILOV /d/temp
$ git add a
```

Then I press tab - it completes current line to "ab" and does not print anything else:

```
// after tab pressing
id@IDANILOV /d/temp
$ git add ab
```

If I press tab second time - it shows "abc" and "abd":

```
// after second tab press
id@IDANILOV /d/temp
$ git add ab
abc  abd

id@IDANILOV /d/temp
$ git add ab
```

But after some update (or maybe I did something inadvertently) - it shows all variants even after first tab press, which is annoying.

Where this behavior could be changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some inputrc file (/etc/inputrc, ~/.inputrc, ...) there is a line like:

```
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```

Remove this line, insert `#` at beginning of line or change `on` to `off`.

Alternatively put

```
bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous off'
```

into your .bashrc

Reference:
http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html#SEC9

Comment: I am on windows so I needed to put bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous off' in my Users\user\.bash_profile